# how do concurrent reads affect Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

am designing a Postgres-based app to handle big data with many users. Data is modelled so that most reads use only three tables, which means all users are looking at the same records at the same time.

Regarding reads (not writes) - do many concurrent reads slow db down, or is the case that once in memory, Postgres displays the same view to all concurrent users without much delay or resource consumption?

Is there a point where the number of reads of the same record slow Postgres down, or, once in memory, there's no more cost to displaying data?

thanks,

Alex Glaros

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *do many concurrent reads slow db down, or is the case that once in memory, Postgres displays the same view to all concurrent users without much delay or resource consumption?*

If the same data is requested over and over again, then yes, it will be kept in memory (provided Postgres has enough memory available to do that).

> *Is there a point where the number of reads of the same record slow Postgres down*

Nothing comes for free, so yes there is overhead involved when concurrent transactions request the same data at **exactly** the same time. Access to the data blocks in memory needs to be synchronized through locks (albeit very lightweight), latches and semaphores.

In a system where the complete data is in memory, the CPU does get the limiting factor. Recent Postgres versions have improved drastically in terms of scalability with multiple concurrent sessions, so make sure you do use the latest version (9.6 or even 10.0).

This refers to multiple transactions requesting the same block of data at **exactly** the same nanosecond though. If the transactions (sessions, connections) typically request different parts of those three tables you will see problems due to synchronization on memory blocks only under very, very heavy load.